# present video and record from webcam - matlab

Tags: matlab, video

I wrote a script that present  movie and record from the webcam. The problem is that it rolls the movie in slow motion. I don't think the problem is from taking the snapshot ( I checked it). This is the code:

```
clear cam  
v = VideoReader('movie.MP4');  
cam = webcam;
vidWriter = VideoWriter('webcam.avi');
open(vidWriter);

%pre loading the frames
for i=1:50
vtemp = readFrame(v);
vid{i}=vtemp;
end

for index = 1:50
    % Acquire frame for processing
    img = snapshot(cam);

    % Write frame to video
    writeVideo(vidWriter, img);

    %show the vid frame
    imshow(vid{index});
end
close(vidWriter);
clear cam
```

Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Set the same fps for your output movie.